# Executing commands with the ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, swing, command-line, process

I want to run the following command from a java file command : "`java hello < C:\iptest\input.txt > C:\outtest\name.txt` "`hello`" will take input from "`C:\iptest\input.txt`" and will produce an output file at "`C:\outtest\name.txt`".
codes i have done

```
       String command[]={"java","hello","< C:\\iptest\\input.txt >","C:\outtest\name.txt"};
       ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder(command);
       pb.directory(new File("E:\"));
```

and now how to go forward i have no idea .Please Help!!

Comment: This is a hyper classic question... And Google has plenty of solutions to your problem. Hint: redirections the way you use them are handled at the shell level, not the process level. See the documentation for `ProcessBuilder`...

Comment: @fge can you give provide me with one link which has solution of anything like this

Comment: Some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+ProcessBuilder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the ProcessBuilder definition on Oracle, which explains how to use this class.  Typically, this is used for executing non-java processes, e.g. .BAT or .EXE processes, but I suppose you could use it to execute any process you wish.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html